# ¿De dónde viene la expresión “tirar al muñeco”?

Tags: modismos, etimología, expresiones, deportes

En el ámbito del fútbol (y supongo que en otros deportes) se usa con frecuencia la expresión "tirar al muñeco". Esta se refiere al acto de disparar el balón a portería sin enfocar, sino más bien golpeando al portero, con el consiguiente fallo de la oportunidad de gol.

Así, es típico leer [cosas como](http://www.defensacentral.com/intranet/pizarraampliada-64592):

> no puede ser que Bale falle delante del portero solo cuando la puedes
>   picar o regatear al portero pero no *tirar al muñeco*

Me pregunto: ¿de dónde viene esta expresión? ¿se usa también en América Latina?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La expresión viene de las casetas de feria en las que se lanzaban bolas de trapo y el participante se llevaba los premios que derribaba con ellas. Un premio habitual era un muñeco de trapo o peluche y, claro, para llevárselo había que *tirar al muñeco* la bola.

En el ámbito de fútbol la expresión es despectiva: el jugador ha tirado el balón como si estuviera en las ferias, a darle al muñeco (el portero), en lugar de como se debe hacer en un partido para marcar gol.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Me he sentido joven al pensar que nunca llegué a ver este juego en las casetas de feria : )

Comment: @fedorqui Ahora me has hecho sentir viejo a mí :D

Comment: Esa expresión se utiliza en toda Latinoamérica, muy popular de hecho. En México también he escuchado la variante ¨tirar al mono¨, dado que en México es común referirse a los muñecos como ´monitos/monos´ (sin relación con el animal).

Answer (score 1):

Sin descartar que la opción que propone Gorpik sea la buena, yo siempre he oído que dicha expresión deriva de los [futbolines](https://www.google.com/search?q=futbolin&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAmoVChMIxuznidijyAIVBrkUCh0q5Q5C&biw=1280&bih=922) y, por extensión, se traslada al fútbol con connotación peyorativa, ya que indica que el jugador que "tira al muñeco" es más un jugador de futbolín que de fútbol.

Comment: ¡Qué interesante! ¿Tienes alguna referencia al respecto?

Comment: Desgraciadamente no, pero durante años hemos usado esa expresión tanto jugando al fútbol como al futbolín, con connotación peyorativa en el futbol y más bien casual en el futbolín

Comment: También se suele abreviar como "tirar al keko", cambiando "muñeco" por "keko", aunque creo que esto es algo bastante reciente

Comment: Es decir que en este caso "tirar al muñeco" sería "no apuntar sino tirar al portero directamente".

Comment: Si, hace referencia a tirar de modo descuidado y sin apuntar, cosa que es típica cuando se juega al futbolín (salvo cuando el jugador es bueno), y que se considera un fallo garrafal e impropio en el fútbol.